# Merge rows based on the same date?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks like the below

```
Date             | ID   | Period | ArchivedBy | ArchivedFlag | Value
2018-01-20 12:23 |23344 |  Q1    |  NULL      |   NULL       | 200
2018-01-20 12:20 |23344 |  NULL  |  P.Tills   |   1          | NULL
2018-01-20 12:19 |23344 |  NULL  |  NULL      |   1          | NULL
```

This table represents all edits made to an agreement (each new edit gets it's own row). If a value hasn't been changed at all, it will say NULL.

so ideally the above would look like the following

```
Date             | ID   | Period | ArchivedBy | ArchivedFlag | Value
2018-01-20       |23344 |  Q1    |  P.Tills   |   1          | 200
```

This returned row should show the latest state of the agreement based on the date. So for the date in my example (2018-01-20) this one row would be returned, combining all changes that were made throughout the day into 1 row which shows how it looks following all the changes throughout the day.

I hope this makes sense?

Thank you!

Comment: What if there are two different values ?

Comment: If there are 2 different values then based on the time stamp, the latest one would be the one that was included in the final row.

Comment: Is that logic only applicable to Value column ?

Comment: No to all the columns. So if at 12:20 the Period ID was Q1 and then at 12:26 someone changed it to Q2, then as Q2 is the last edit in that day it would be included in the single row output

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Row_Number` and `Group by`

```
SELECT [Date] = Cast([Date] AS DATE),
       ID,
       Max(period),
       Max(ArchivedBy),
       Max(ArchivedFlag),
       Max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [Value] END)
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Rn = Row_number()OVER(partition BY Cast([Date] AS DATE), ID ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
        FROM   Yourtable)a
GROUP  BY Cast([Date] AS DATE),
          ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose 2 solutions.

**Simple**

For each day select top 1 NOT NULL value:

```
SELECT G.ID, G.GD Date, Period.*, ArchivedBy.*, Value.* FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT ID, CAST(Date AS Date) GD FROM T) G
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Period FROM T WHERE Period IS NOT NULL AND CAST(Date AS Date)=GD ORDER BY Date DESC) Period
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ArchivedBy FROM T WHERE ArchivedBy IS NOT NULL AND CAST(Date AS Date)=GD ORDER BY Date DESC) ArchivedBy
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM T WHERE Value IS NOT NULL AND CAST(Date AS Date)=GD ORDER BY Date DESC) Value
```

**Optimized (intuitively, not tested*)**

Use varbinary sorting rules and aggregation, manually order NULLs:

```
SELECT CAST(Date AS Date), ID,
  CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(Arch),9, LEN(MAX(Arch))) AS varchar(10)) ArchivedBy --unbox
  --other columns
  FROM
(
    SELECT Date, ID,
        CAST(CASE WHEN ArchivedBy IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(Date AS Date) ORDER BY Date) ELSE 0 END AS varbinary(MAX))+CAST(ArchivedBy AS varbinary(MAX)) Arch --box
        --other columns
    FROM T
) Tab
GROUP BY ID, CAST(Date AS Date)
```